# Why is I/O caching performance so much better on Linux than Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, performance, cache

This question is really just a port of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916011/how-do-i-get-windows-to-go-as-fast-as-linux-for-compiling-c) on Stack Overflow:

The emerging consensus from that question is that Linux has superior caching to Windows but the specific reasons why have not been pinned down. Does anybody here have any greater insight into the technical explanation?

A few people, myself included, have also noticed that Windows can actually perform better in a VM on top of Linux than it does on the raw iron (native hardware). Why would having Linux host Windows as a client OS increase the Windows performance?

Comment: I am not sure if you mean more aggressive as opposed to better. There are times when you want less caching, not more. Are there objective benchmarks used to test compiler speed that can be run on more than one OS for the same program?

Comment: Because it is Not Windows...;->

Comment: I think this is all rather subjective unless you come up with some hard data to back your claims up.

Comment: Do you have anything more than anecdotal "we have noticed" comparisons of one being faster than the other? Benchmarks maybe? Otherwise I'd have to say that it may just be in your head.. also different architectures have different overheads and Windows has a lot of legacy support built in.

Comment: Should benchmark results come along, I would make sure that the following registry key is set to 1, and not zero, as this will make the disk cache on windows much more aggressive/larger. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager     
\Memory Management`

Comment: The SO question not only deals with the file system, but differences in compilers, build systems, source control systems, etc etc. Literally 1000 factors.  For example. "On Windows, we compile with VC++. On Linux, we compile with gcc." That alone isn't **just caching** nor does it have to do with file systems.  I just see this becoming anecdoctal as SO itself has already passed over that small fact.

Comment: I think that unless someone posts benchmarks so that we have numbers to work with, this is just not constructive.